# Is it possible to highlight an area of the page after user clicks a same-page link?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to highlight an area of the page after user clicks a same-page link? I am using a 3 column layout and the part of the page I'm linking to is located on the right hand side. I just want to make sure the user sees it instantly, rather than having to look for it.

Thanks!

Edit: Thanks for the replies! I think it would be better for me to use the :target method as I understand how it work. I have very little knowledge of jquery and prefer to understand what I'm coding if at all possible :-P

Comment: You could highlight the containing `div` on click with javascript or jquery. With some code to work with, we could give examples.

Answer (score 3):

Use [the `:target` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#target-pseudo) to select it in your stylesheet for highlighting.

```
<a href="#foo">Link</a>
```

and

```
<div id="foo">content here</div>
```

and

```
div:target { background: yellow; }
```

in your stylesheet

Comment: i like this, css way, no $fancy javascript. Just 'UI'. Thanks for the remembrance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript or Jquery to achieve this. Using code similar like this

```
$("#link").click(function(){
    $("#myDivToShow").css("background-color","maroon");
});
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinyadav/36r64/)

You can also use animation or css transition to show effects with background-color as well.

Comment: Maybe add a setTimeOut function for temporary highlighting?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, yes you can do this with CSS with :active, :hover, but this implies:

- Nesting your columns in your navigation, with an absolute position
- Having to manually specify the height of the columns or make them relative to the content in it.

Here is a sample:
http://jsbin.com/upapey/2/edit

And the code for later reference:

The HTML:

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="nav">
      <a href="#col_1">Col 1
        <div id="col_1" class="col"></div>
      </a>
      <a href="#col_2">Col 2
        <div id="col_2" class="col"></div>
      </a>
      <a href="#col_3">Col 3
        <div id="col_3" class="col"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#nav {
  width: 100%;
}
a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
div.col {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 320px;
  max-height: 2000px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: default !important;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
div#col_2 {
  margin-left: 25%;
}
div#col_3 {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
/* a:hover must be before a:active, else the latter won't be triggered */
a:hover .col { 
  border: 1px solid green;
}
a:active .col {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```